# Photon Engine: Client cannot connect to existing room and creates same room

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am running a server and client. Both are able to connect to master but the client is unable to find the room that the server created and creates its own room with the same name. Do not get an error that game already exists from the master, just says Game does not exist.

This only happens when I build the server but works in Unity Editor just fine. I am not sure if the reason is that Server and Client have different build names but the app id and game version are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue was you need to specify a specific region in the PhotonServerSettings. You can find the available regions here: https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/connection-and-authentication/regions#best_region_considerations