# Photon creating new room instead of connecting to already existing one?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

When I create a build of the game, everything works normally. However, when the second player tries to connect to the room with the name, it says that the room does not exist and if I create a room with the first rooms name it gets created instead of saying "room already exists".

I thought it could be a region problem, but in PhotonServerSettings, the "Fixed Region" is set to "eu", "Use Name Server" checked on, and "Dev Region" set to null (left it empty). In the build settings I set "development build" to false.

I don't understand why the two games would not be in the same region based on what I mentioned before?

[Picture of the PhotonServerSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyeY9.png)

This is the code for creating/joining a room:

```
public void CreateRoom()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CreateInputField.text))
    {
        return;
    }
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(CreateInputField.text);
}
public void JoinRoom()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(JoinInputField.text))
    {
        return;
    }
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(JoinInputField.text);
}
public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Game");
}

public override void OnCreateRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
{
    failText.text = message;
}
public override void OnJoinRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
{
    failText.text = message;
}
```

}

(for some reason I cant put the entire script but these are the important parts)

Comment: How are you searching for the room?  Please provide that code.  In my code, I list all available rooms and allow selection that way.

Comment: @hijinxbassist The Pun ID in the picture is not the full thing, there is quite a lot left of it so I don't think that's a problem. I only have "Create" and "join", so you can create a room with a name that you input, and if you want to join you have to enter a room name. There is no room list or something like that. If you play with friends you share the name and they can input it and click "join". This worked for a while, but now it just stopped working; you can't find the room that is created and you can create a room with the same name.

Comment: Are you allowing sufficient time for the room to be created and accessible?  Based on the documentation it does not seem like region should affect finding the room if it exists.  `a roomName is always "global" for your application` where application `is defined by AppId, Game- and PUN-version.`  Are you positive the most up to date version is being run by both players?

Comment: I think I'm using the 2.40 version of Pun? But either way, the game is just a prototype right now so when I build the game to test it, I open it twice and try to connect from the two "runs of the game". So I build it, run it, create a room with a name, run the app again, this time "join" the room that I created before. Another guy with the exact same problem said he fixed it, but I assume (based on the info in the question) that is not a fix for me. The question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964982/photon-engine-client-cannot-connect-to-existing-room-and-creates-same-room

Comment: What did you mean by "Are you allowing sufficient time for the room to be created and accessible" tho? I assume I am allowing it because this worked before I changed some stuff, but I'm not so sure

Comment: I just entered "eu" in the "Dev Region" in the PhotonServerSettings and set "development build" to true and it worked... But based on what I read the finished game should not be using dev regions? It seems that "development build" is the main problem here, but I have no idea how and why ;)

Comment: I looked over the linked answer, and he does seem to indicate it was solved by setting a specific region.  I imagine he also has development build set to true.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.  Might be a good question for the [Forum](https://forum.photonengine.com/sso) or their Support `developer@photonengine.com`

Comment: No, thank you for your time. Thanks to you I at least know it's a region problem and not a code problem which is a hugeeeee relife ;)